# Eliminate duplicate code re: lambda loop parameter passing

Tags: javascript, code-duplication, lambda

### Problem

An array defines these elements:

```
var equipment = new Array( "bakeware", "cookware", "kitchenware", "utensils" );
```

A function exists that associates these equipment types with editable fields:

```
function register_equipment( equipment ) {
  $('#recipe-equipment-' + equipment).append(
    '<span class="edit-recipe-equipment"></span><br />' );

  $('.edit-recipe-equipment').editable( 'php/save.php', {
    onblur   : 'submit',
    style    : 'display: inline',
    maxlength: 15,
    size     : 10
  });

  return true;
}
```

This allows users to click on the field and edit its value. The input field disappears when the user finishes editing.

The following code is duplicated four times (once per equipment item):

```
  $('#equipment-new-bakeware').click( function() {
    return register_equipment( 'bakeware' );
  });
```

This works, but it is not ideal.

### Question

How would you write the code such that there is no duplication?

The following does not work, but shows the intent to remove the duplication:

```
for( var i = 0; i < equipment.length; i++ ) {
  $('#equipment-new-' + equipment[i]).click( function() {
    return register_equipment( equipment[i] );
  });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Think this is because `i` will have value `4` after leaving the loop. The, when the click function gets called it `sees` this value of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is to create another scope to capture the correct value. Bit long winded, but this is the idea.

```
function createOnClick (i) {
  // i will be captured in this function and used below
  return function () {
    register_equipment( equipment[i] );
  };
}

for( var i = 0; i < equipment.length; i++ ) {
  $('#equipment-new-' + equipment[i]).click(createOnClick(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the equipment type from the id of the clicked object and use that:

```
var registerEquipment = function() {
    var equipmentType = $(this).attr('id').replace('equipment-new-', '');
    return register_equipment(equipmentType);
  };

for( var i = 0; i < equipment.length; i++ ) { 
  $('#equipment-new-' + equipment[i]).click(registerEquipment);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Briguy37. While this looks like it will work flawlessly, Paul's solution is a bit more robust as it has no dependency on the `id` attribute.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: You're welcome, and although Paul's answer currently does have a dependency on id for initialization, that could easily be removed whereas mine could not, so I see your point.  However, if you plan on having a lot of equipment on your page, please keep in mind that with this solution you'll only ever need one function,  as opposed to needing one for every piece of equipment.

Comment: Ah, you mean only one extra function loaded into memory? (It appears that both solutions only codify one extra function, which is my main concern: maintainability.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for( item in equipment ) { 
  $('#equipment-new-' + item).click = function () {
    register_equipment(item);
  }
}
```

Give it a try ;)